# Leer datos de una tabla en google sheets , y enviarlos por correo electrónico

Tags: javascript

Tengo una hoja de google sheets con espacios para diligenciar en el rango B13:H21, 
el usuario ingresa información pero puede que algunas filas del rango queden sin diligenciar. El código toma todo el rango descrito anteriormente y envía un correo electrónico de manera automatica cuando oprimo el botón enviar en el cual se encuentra la sgte macro:

```
    function Suministros() {

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B5");
      var Fecha = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F5");
      var Ciudad = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B7");
      var Proceso = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F7");
      var CC = dataRange.getValues();

      if (CC != "") {

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A8");
      var correo = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C8");
      var gerente = dataRange.getValues();

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B13");
      var cod1 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C13");
      var Form1 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F13");
      var Cant1 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G13");
      var Exis1 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H13");
      var Entr1 = dataRange.getValues();

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B14");
      var cod2 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C14");
      var Form2 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F14");
      var Cant2 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G14");
      var Exis2 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H14");
      var Entr2 = dataRange.getValues();

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B15");
      var cod3 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C15");
      var Form3 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F15");
      var Cant3 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G15");
      var Exis3 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H15");
      var Entr3 = dataRange.getValues();

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B16");
      var cod4 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C16");
      var Form4 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F16");
      var Cant4 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G16");
      var Exis4 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H16");
      var Entr4 = dataRange.getValues();

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B17");
      var cod5 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C17");
      var Form5 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F17");
      var Cant5 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G17");
      var Exis5 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H17");
      var Entr5 = dataRange.getValues();

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B18");
      var cod6 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C18");
      var Form6 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F18");
      var Cant6 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G18");
      var Exis6 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H18");
      var Entr6 = dataRange.getValues();

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B19");
      var cod7 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C19");
      var Form7 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F19");
      var Cant7 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G19");
      var Exis7 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H19");
      var Entr7 = dataRange.getValues();

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B20");
      var cod8 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C20");
      var Form8 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F20");
      var Cant8 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G20");
      var Exis8 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H20");
      var Entr8 = dataRange.getValues();

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B21");
      var cod9 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C21");
      var Form9 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F21");
      var Cant9 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G21");
      var Exis9 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H21");
      var Entr9 = dataRange.getValues();

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B25");
      var asesor1 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("e25");
      var cedula1 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F25");
      var cantidad1 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G25");
      var gama1 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H25");
      var rango1 = dataRange.getValues();

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B26");
      var asesor2 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("e26");
      var cedula2 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F26");
      var cantidad2 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G26");
      var gama2 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H26");
      var rango2 = dataRange.getValues();

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B27");
      var asesor3 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("e27");
      var cedula3 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F27");
      var cantidad3 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G27");
      var gama3 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H27");
      var rango3 = dataRange.getValues();

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B28");
      var asesor4 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("e28");
      var cedula4 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F28");
      var cantidad4 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G28");
      var gama4 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H28");
      var rango4 = dataRange.getValues();  

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B29");
      var asesor5 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("e29");
      var cedula5 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F29");
      var cantidad5 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G29");
      var gama5 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H29");
      var rango5 = dataRange.getValues();

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B30");
      var asesor6 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("e30");
      var cedula6 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F30");
      var cantidad6 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G30");
      var gama6 = dataRange.getValues();
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H30");
      var rango6 = dataRange.getValues();

      var direccion = correo;
      var mensaje = '<b>Señor(a)  ' +gerente+ '<br\>Solicito por favor la aprobacion del siguiente pedido.';
        mensaje += '<br\>.   ';
        mensaje += '<html><body>';
        mensaje += '<table border="1" width="95%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>FECHA</b></td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>CIUDAD</b></td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>PROCESO</b></td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>CENTRO DE COSTOS</b></td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Fecha +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Ciudad +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Proceso +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ CC +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '</table>';
        mensaje += '</body></html>';

        mensaje += '<html><body>';
        mensaje += '<table border="1" width="95%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" colspan="5" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>SOLICITUD DE SUMINISTROS</b></td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" rowspan="2" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Código</b></td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" rowspan="2" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Nombre del Formato</b></td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" colspan="3" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>CANTIDAD</b></td>';

        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Solicitada</b></td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Existente</b></td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Entregada</b></td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod1 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form1 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant1 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis1 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr1 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod2 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form2 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant2 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis2 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr2 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod3 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form3 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant3 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis3 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr3 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod4 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form4 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant4 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis4 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr4 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod5 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form5 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant5 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis5 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr5 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod6 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form6 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant6 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis6 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr6 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod7 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form7 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant7 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis7 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr7 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod8 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form8 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant8 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis8 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr8 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod9 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form9 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant9 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis9 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr9 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '</table>';
        mensaje += '</body></html>';

        mensaje += '<html><body>';
        mensaje += '<table border="1" width="95%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Nombre del Ejecutivo de Ventas</b></td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Documento de Identidad</b></td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Cantidad</b></td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Gama Alta/Baja</b></td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Rango</b></td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ asesor1 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cedula1 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cantidad1 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ gama1 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ rango1 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ asesor2 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cedula2 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cantidad2 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ gama2 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ rango2 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ asesor3 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cedula3 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cantidad3 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ gama3 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ rango3 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ asesor4 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cedula4 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cantidad4 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ gama4 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ rango4 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ asesor5 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cedula5 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cantidad5 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ gama5 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ rango5 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '<tr>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ asesor6 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cedula6 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cantidad6 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ gama6 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ rango6 +'</td>';
        mensaje += '</tr>';
        mensaje += '</table>';
        mensaje += '</body></html>';

      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Solicitud Enviada');


   //armamos el asunto del mail

  var asunto ='SOLICITUD DE SUMINISTROS';
  var body = mensaje;
  var options = { htmlBody : mensaje };

  //usamos la API de Gmail para enviar el mail.
  GmailApp.sendEmail(direccion, asunto, mensaje, options);
 }  
  else
  {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Debe diligenciar el centro de costos para continuar'); 
}
};
```

El código trabaja bien, pero quiero simplificarlo, porque realmente son cosas repetitivas, leer los datos en una fila y crear una tabla y enviarla por mail, con dicha información,

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Muchas Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

logré solucionar el requerimiento, sólo agregue un condicional antes de generar cada una de las filas de la tabla, en la que me valida si el primer campo de la fila está vacío, si lo está no dibuja esa fila. Aquí está el código con los ajustes:

function Suministros() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B5");
  var Fecha = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F5");
  var Ciudad = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B7");
  var Proceso = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F7");
  var CC = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F9");
  var ventas = dataRange.getValues();

if (CC != "") {

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A8");
  var correo = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C8");
  var gerente = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B13");
  var cod1 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C13");
  var Form1 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F13");
  var Cant1 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G13");
  var Exis1 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H13");
  var Entr1 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B14");
  var cod2 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C14");
  var Form2 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F14");
  var Cant2 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G14");
  var Exis2 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H14");
  var Entr2 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B15");
  var cod3 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C15");
  var Form3 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F15");
  var Cant3 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G15");
  var Exis3 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H15");
  var Entr3 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B16");
  var cod4 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C16");
  var Form4 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F16");
  var Cant4 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G16");
  var Exis4 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H16");
  var Entr4 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B17");
  var cod5 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C17");
  var Form5 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F17");
  var Cant5 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G17");
  var Exis5 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H17");
  var Entr5 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B18");
  var cod6 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C18");
  var Form6 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F18");
  var Cant6 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G18");
  var Exis6 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H18");
  var Entr6 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B19");
  var cod7 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C19");
  var Form7 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F19");
  var Cant7 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G19");
  var Exis7 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H19");
  var Entr7 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B20");
  var cod8 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C20");
  var Form8 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F20");
  var Cant8 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G20");
  var Exis8 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H20");
  var Entr8 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B21");
  var cod9 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C21");
  var Form9 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F21");
  var Cant9 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G21");
  var Exis9 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H21");
  var Entr9 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B22");
  var cod10 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C22");
  var Form10 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F22");
  var Cant10 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G22");
  var Exis10 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H22");
  var Entr10 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B23");
  var cod11 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C23");
  var Form11 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F23");
  var Cant11 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G23");
  var Exis11 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H23");
  var Entr11 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B24");
  var cod12 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C24");
  var Form12 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F24");
  var Cant12 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G24");
  var Exis12 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H24");
  var Entr12 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B25");
  var cod13 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C25");
  var Form13 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F25");
  var Cant13 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G25");
  var Exis13 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H25");
  var Entr13 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B26");
  var cod14 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C26");
  var Form14 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F26");
  var Cant14 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G26");
  var Exis14 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H26");
  var Entr14 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B27");
  var cod15 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C27");
  var Form15 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F27");
  var Cant15 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G27");
  var Exis15 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H27");
  var Entr15 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B28");
  var cod16 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C28");
  var Form16 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F28");
  var Cant16 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G28");
  var Exis16 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H28");
  var Entr16 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B29");
  var cod17 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C29");
  var Form17 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F29");
  var Cant17 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G29");
  var Exis17 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H29");
  var Entr17 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B33");
  var asesor1 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("e33");
  var cedula1 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F33");
  var cantidad1 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G33");
  var gama1 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H33");
  var rango1 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B34");
  var asesor2 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("e34");
  var cedula2 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F34");
  var cantidad2 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G34");
  var gama2 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H34");
  var rango2 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B35");
  var asesor3 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("e35");
  var cedula3 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F35");
  var cantidad3 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G35");
  var gama3 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H35");
  var rango3 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B36");
  var asesor4 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("e36");
  var cedula4 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F36");
  var cantidad4 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G36");
  var gama4 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H36");
  var rango4 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B37");
  var asesor5 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("e37");
  var cedula5 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F37");
  var cantidad5 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G37");
  var gama5 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H37");
  var rango5 = dataRange.getValues();

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("B38");
  var asesor6 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("e38");
  var cedula6 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("F38");
  var cantidad6 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("G38");
  var gama6 = dataRange.getValues();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("H38");
  var rango6 = dataRange.getValues();

var direccion = correo; 
  var mensaje = '**Señor(a)  ' +gerente+ 'Solicito por favor la aprobacion del siguiente pedido.';
    mensaje += '.   ';
    mensaje += '';
    mensaje += '';
    mensaje += '';
    mensaje += '**FECHA**';
    mensaje += '**CIUDAD**';
    mensaje += '**PROCESO**';
    mensaje += 'CENTRO DE COSTOS**';
    mensaje += '';
    mensaje += '';
    mensaje += ''+ Fecha +'';
    mensaje += ''+ Ciudad +'';
    mensaje += ''+ Proceso +'';
    mensaje += ''+ CC +'';
    mensaje += '';
    mensaje += '';
    mensaje += '';

```
mensaje += '<html><body>';
mensaje += '<table border="1" width="95%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center" colspan="5" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>SOLICITUD DE SUMINISTROS</b></td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center" rowspan="2" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Código</b></td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center" rowspan="2" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Nombre del Formato</b></td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center" colspan="3" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>CANTIDAD</b></td>';

mensaje += '</tr>';
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Solicitada</b></td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Existente</b></td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Entregada</b></td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod1 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form1 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant1 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis1 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr1 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';

if (cod2 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod2 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form2 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant2 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis2 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr2 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
  }
if (cod3 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod3 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form3 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant3 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis3 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr3 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
}
if (cod4 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod4 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form4 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant4 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis4 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr4 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
 } 
if (cod5 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod5 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form5 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant5 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis5 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr5 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
}

if (cod6 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod6 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form6 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant6 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis6 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr6 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
}  

if (cod7 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod7 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form7 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant7 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis7 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr7 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
  }

if (cod8 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod8 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form8 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant8 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis8 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr8 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
   }
if (cod9 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod9 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form9 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant9 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis9 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr9 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
  }
if (cod10 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod10 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form10 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant10 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis10 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr10 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
  }
if (cod11 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod11 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form11 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant11 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis11 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr11 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
  }
if (cod12 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod12 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form12 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant12 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis12 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr12 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
  }
if (cod13 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod13 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form13 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant13 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis13 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr13 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
  }
if (cod14 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod14 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form14 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant14 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis14 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr14 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
  }
if (cod15 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod15 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form15 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant15 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis15 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr15 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
  }
if (cod16 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod16 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form16 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant16 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis16 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr16 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
  }
if (cod17 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cod17 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Form17 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Cant17 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Exis17 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ Entr17 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
  }
mensaje += '</table>';
mensaje += '</body></html>';


if (ventas == 1 ) {
mensaje += '<html><body>';
mensaje += '<table border="1" width="95%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Nombre del Ejecutivo de Ventas</b></td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Documento de Identidad</b></td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Cantidad</b></td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Gama Alta/Baja</b></td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center" bgcolor="0080C0" style="color:#ffffff"><b>Rango</b></td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';

  if (asesor1 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ asesor1 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cedula1 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cantidad1 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ gama1 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ rango1 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
    }
if (asesor2 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ asesor2 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cedula2 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cantidad2 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ gama2 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ rango2 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
  }  
if (asesor3 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ asesor3 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cedula3 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cantidad3 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ gama3 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ rango3 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
  }
if (asesor4 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ asesor4 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cedula4 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cantidad4 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ gama4 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ rango4 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
  }
if (asesor5 != "" ) {  
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ asesor5 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cedula5 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cantidad5 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ gama5 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ rango5 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
}
if (asesor6 != "" ) {
mensaje += '<tr>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ asesor6 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cedula6 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ cantidad6 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ gama6 +'</td>';
mensaje += '<td align="center">'+ rango6 +'</td>';
mensaje += '</tr>';
  }
mensaje += '</table>';
mensaje += '</body></html>';
}
```

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Solicitud Enviada');

//armamos el asunto del mail
  var asunto ='SOLICITUD DE SUMINISTROS';
  var body = mensaje;
  var options = { htmlBody : mensaje };

//usamos la API de Gmail para enviar el mail.
  GmailApp.sendEmail(direccion, asunto, mensaje, options);
 }
  else
  {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Debe diligenciar el centro de costos para continuar'); 
}
};